# CS0433: Ambiguous Reference System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2

I am using VS2015 with Resharper for WebAPI 2.0 project. Trying to use System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetRequestContext gives me an error saying

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'HttpRequestMessageExtensions' exists in both 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I've tried editing web.config to read

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" batch="false" />
```

Also as suggested in numerous posts - restarted visual studio, clear resharper cache, rebuild the solution.

Nothing helps and I am still seeing this error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what happens when you use the namespace to specify which one you want to use? ie instead of `foo.GetRequestContext` try `System.Net.Http.Formatting.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetRequestContext` or `System.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetRequestContext`
?

Comment: I am using     System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions
Which is the fully qualified path.

Comment: paste the relevant section of code in your original question please, including the import definitions

Comment: Still occurring in VS 2017 .NET4.6.2. No solutions?

Comment: Apparentely you are using both System.Net.Http.Formatting and System.Web.Http as a reference. Do you need both of them references? Since it is a webapi project, maybe just System.Net.Http.Formatting would do it.

Comment: The following question was raised in the context of ASP.NET core, but it looks very similar. The answer provided is essentially the same as Rodrigo Werlang's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144611/asp-net-core-build-error-httprequestmessageextensions

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [“extern alias”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansonh/2006/09/27/extern-alias-walkthrough/) to manage two classes with the same namespace.

First, define de name of your custom alias in the properties of the assembly:

[image]

Then, in the code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    extern alias Alias1;
    extern alias Alias2;

    using namespace1 = Alias1::System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions;
    using namespace2 = Alias2::System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions;

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            // ...
            namespace1.GetRequestContext(request);
            //namespace2.GetRequestContext(request); // error


        }
```