# asp.net core build error : 'HttpRequestMessageExtensions'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

Using ASPNet Core 1.1 Web API template and trying to create a response on Post. Getting the below error while building the project. Thanks for your help !

> Controllers\MessagesController.cs(37,28,37,72): error CS0433: The type
>   'HttpRequestMessageExtensions' exists in both
>   'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Answer (score 1):

You should remove reference to `System.Web.Http`, as ASP.NET Core doesn't use it.